# Issue with regex separating slug and lastname in a list

Tags: python, regex, python-re

My string is:

```
test_string = "@@@__slug1^^__firstname lastname@@@^^^ @@@__slug2^^__firstname1 lastname1@@@^^^"
```

I am trying to separate slug and lastname in a list my output will be like.

```
slug_list = [slug1,slug2]
name_list=[firstname lastname,firstname1 lastname1]
```

I try to first search all the slug my code for the same is.

```
import re
test_string = "@@@__slug1^^__firstname lastname@@@^^^ @@@__deletepurpose^^__Delete Purpose@@@^^^"
pattern = "@@@__\|(''*?)\|^^"
substring = re.search(pattern, test_string).group(1)
print(substring)
```

But it does not find a match as it is giving me the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error.

What is wrong with the pattern I am using?

Comment: Not sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/ can be used to close this question: it is not the problem of running a regex against several strings that can match and fail to match a certain pattern, the problem is in the pattern itself. We use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/ to close with when the problem is that within a list of tested strings, there are those that match and those that do not, and OP forgets to check for a match before accessing a group value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
@@@__(.*?)\^\^__(.*?)@@@\^\^\^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RDiDCf/1/). *Details*:

- `@@@__` - a literal string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\^\^__` - a `^^__` literal string
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `@@@\^\^\^` - a literal `@@@^^^` string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XlGSm0):

```py
import re
test_string = "@@@__slug1^^__firstname lastname@@@^^^ @@@__deletepurpose^^__Delete Purpose@@@^^^"
pattern = r"@@@__(.*?)\^\^__(.*?)@@@\^\^\^"
matches = re.findall(pattern, test_string)
print("Slug list:", [x for x,y in matches])
print("Name list:", [y for x,y in matches])
```

Output:

```
Slug list: ['slug1', 'deletepurpose']
Name list: ['firstname lastname', 'Delete Purpose']
```